# How to compile 32 bit Qt project on 64 bit OS?

Tags: qt, target-platform

I am using Qt5.7 on 64 bit Windows 10. I made my project with 64 bit compiling option. But now I have to switch to 32 bit compiling option. My Qt plugin in VS2015 shows
'There's no Qt version assigned to this project for platform Win32. Please use change Qt version feature and choose a valid Qt version for this platform'.
But Qt plugin shows options only for 64 bit (msvc2015_64). How can I change it to 32 bit?

Comment: Did you do any prior research? When searching for some keywords in your question, I get a ton of links ... https://forum.qt.io/topic/3641/how-to-force-32bit-target-compiling-linking-on-64bit-platform-64bit-ubuntu-10-10-qt-4-7-0-qtcreator-2-0-1

Comment: Yes I already checked it. That person is using an old version of Qt, Ubuntu and Qt Creator. But I am using Qt Designer with Qt Plugin for VS2015. It didn't help me.

Comment: The question and the message for the question are not about the same thing: we can compile the project many different ways without any VS. Qt Options / Qt Versions / point where the required Qt is. http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Visual_Studio_Add_in.php